# Solved: Relative Efficiency of Average versus Maximum Order Statistic on a Uniform Distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics, efficiency

$\newcommand{\szdp}[1]{\!\left(#1\right)}\newcommand{\eff}{\operatorname{eff}}$
**Problem Statement:** Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ denote a random sample from the uniform
distribution on the interval $(\theta, \theta+1).$ Let
$$\hat\theta_1=\overline{Y}-\frac12\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\hat\theta_2=Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}.$$
Find the efficiency of $\hat\theta_1$ relative to $\hat\theta_2.$
[Note: this is Problem 9.3**b** in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer.]

**My Attempt:** It is fairly straight-forward to show that both $\hat\theta_1$ and $\hat\theta_2$ are unbiased estimators of $\theta.$ Note that the distribution of $Y_i$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(y)&=
\begin{cases}
1,&\theta<y<\theta+1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere,}
\end{cases}\\
F(y)&=
\begin{cases}
0,&y\le\theta\\
y-\theta,&\theta<y<\theta+1\\
1,&\theta+1\le y,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
so that the distribution of the maximum order statistic $Y_{(n)}:=\max(Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
g_{(n)}(y)
&=n[F(y)]^{n-1}\,f(y)\\
&=
\begin{cases}
n(y-\theta)^{n-1},&\theta<y<\theta+1\\
0,&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Now we must compute variances:
\begin{align*}
V\szdp{\hat\theta_1}
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\,\sum_{i=1}^n V(Y_i)\\
&=\frac{1}{12n}\\
V\szdp{\hat\theta_2}
&=V\szdp{Y_{(n)}}\\
&=n\int_\theta^{\theta+1}y^2\,(y-\theta)^{n-1}\,dy-\theta^2\\
&=n\left[\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{2\theta}{n+1}+\frac{\theta^2}{n}\right]-\theta^2\\
&=\frac{n}{n+2}+\frac{2n\theta}{n+1}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)+2n(n+2)\theta}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac{n(n+1+2n\theta+4\theta)}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align*}
Finally, we compute the efficiency as
\begin{align*}
\eff\szdp{\hat\theta_1,\hat\theta_2}
&=\frac{V\szdp{\hat\theta_2}}{V\szdp{\hat\theta_1}}\\
&=\frac{12n^2(n+1+2n\theta+4\theta)}{(n+1)(n+2)}.
\end{align*}

**My Question:** This is not the book's answer, which is
$$\frac{12n^2}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}.$$
Am I doing something wrong, or is the book wrong, or are we both wrong?

Comment: Then you can answer your own Q, that is, in the answer box, so that this does not linger on as unresolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. It is not the case that
$$(E(Y_{(n)}))^2=\theta^2.$$
$\hat\theta_2$ is the unbiased estimator, not $Y_{(n)}.$ If I carry through this correction, I get the book's answer.